# Resizing the post-thumbnails img in single post display

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been trying to resize the post size in the single view post page for the thumbnails, but I cant seem to get it working. I am trying to archive the following:

- Keep the thumbnail size as is in the blog page
- Resize the thumbnails that carries over to the single post view to a larger post size (double the size actually).
- I found the following in mytheme/includes/theme-init.php

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) { 
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 600, 440, true ); 
    add_image_size( 'slider-post-thumbnail', 660, 466, true );
}
```

As you can see I doubled the size parameters from 300, 220 to as it is now, but this does not seem to update the single post display. I cleared cache and anything else, but they dont seem to take my changes. I even edited the post and readded the img, but to no help.

I also tried to look for the same two parameters by doing a wide search in my entire wordpress installation + its theme files, but these parameters (the 300, 220) only show up in theme-init.php I also looked all over in my styles.css to make sure nothing there was overwriting the display of the img, but there was no indication.

Does anyone know how I can solve this issue, and is there something somewhere I need to make sure is activated?

Answer (score 0):

When you say you readded the image, did you re-upload it, or just add it from the media library?  Images are only resized when the files are first uploaded, so if you added your new thumbnail size after uploading the image, the size you're after may not exist.

You can explicitly create the image with something like the [post thumbnail editor plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-thumbnail-editor/), or just recreate them all with the [regenerate thumbnails plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) (though I've never used that one myself).  At least that way you can exclude the possibility that the correctly sized image doesn't exist.